# Is the 'on' method in this node.js code a JavaScript method or a node method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I couldn't find this answer on Google because 'on' is such a common word.
In this node.js example:

```
conn.on('close', function() {
var pos =   connections.indexOf(conn);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        connections.splice(pos, 1);
    }
});
```

There is a `.on` method(?). What it does? It is a JavaScript method? Or it is something you only find in node? I'm kind of confused because I think I saw something like `.on` on jQuery. Is it similar to the jQuery `.live` event handler?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Everything is a javascript method. It's part of the Node API and it has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is a method from Node's EventEmitter class:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener

Answer (score 18):

In this case, `on` is a node method. jQuery also has a method of the same name, and they're used for basically the same purpose - binding event handlers to events by their string name. In fact the signatures look identical to me, IIRC.

Pure JavaScript doesn't have such a method.

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for an easy explanation, it is node native implementation, and it's an alias of addListener(evtName, func)
Check the [API here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener)

Answer (score 3):

As you may know, Node.js is evented, thus listening for events (pub-sub), just like jQuery or Backbone for example.

In Node.js, you usually bind functions (using 'on' or other functions) to listen to events.

From the Node.js [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/events.html#events):

> For example net.Server emits an event each time a peer connects to it,
>   a fs.readStream emits an event when the file is opened. All objects
>   which emit events are instances of events.EventEmitter. You can access
>   this module by doing: require("events");